# Dynamics CRM: Javascript triggers open dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog, dynamics-crm-2011, onload-event, topendialog

I am trying to create javascript to open a dialog.

once the value of a field called 'new_mstatus' on the current record is equal to 'Inactive' and user intends to open this record,  a dialog will open.

```js
function opendialog() {
   if(Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1)
   {
       Xrm.Page.data.entity.save(null);
       return;
   }

   // If inactive then trigger dialog
   if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_mstatus").getValue() == 'Inactive') {

       window.open("/" + Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName() + "/cs/dialog/rundialog.aspx?DialogId=%7b840D55C6-8307-450B-977F-6A9C9844CCE7%7d&EntityName=appointment&ObjectId=" + Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId());

       // Set as being displayed so it doesn't trigger again on load
       Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_displayeddialog").setValue(true);

   }
}
```

but it doesnt work. even no error popup.

can someone give me a hand with this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: which type is the field "new_mstatus"?

Comment: Have you tried debugging in IE? Then you can follow the code step by step.

Comment: What is calling your opendialog function?

Comment: @GuidoPreite the field is option set with 3 values. potential, inactive and active.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are checking the optionset numeric value (took by `getValue` function) against a string (`Inactive` in your case).

So you have 2 possibilities:

- Find the optionset value for `Inactive` (this is the correct way)

```js
// assuming 900000000 is the value for Inactive
if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_mstatus").getValue() == 900000000) {
```

- Get the label of the optionset instead the value using the function `getText` (not suggested because will not work if the label change, for example in multilanguage environments)

```js
if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_mstatus").getText() =='Inactive') {
```